# How to determine a database constraint violation in java?

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, constraints

I am relying on the database to tell me if there is a uniqueness violation so I would like to know when the exception I am getting is some sort of constraint violation.  It looks like this is exactly what I need: `java.sql.SQLNonTransientException`

But it is new to 1.6 and I'm not confident my database drivers are new enough. I use many DBMSs and have many clients, so relying on the driver to be up-to-date is difficult.

Is there a generic way to check for this pre-java 1.6 other than searching the exception message for "constraint"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no general mechanism for this. It's dependent on the database and the JDBC driver you use.

`SQLException` has `getErrorCode` and `getSQLState` methods that return information that you can use to determine the fine meaning of a given exception, but you'll have to make it specific to driver+database.

[Spring uses those same indications and a database-specific lookup table to translate `SQLException` into its own database-agnostic hierarchy of exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-SQLExceptionTranslator). You may be able to use that, or at least look at its sour e code to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help, what you said is what I expected, i.e., there isn't a vendor neutral way of doing this. I can deal with it in an ugly way, I just wanted to see how ugly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In general: don't expect the database driver to always return the 'right' exception. It might be better to check:

- The SQL state
- The vendor code
- The actual message text (driver dependent!)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the message text because some (most?) drivers might return a localised error text depending on the locale of the client.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right (very annoying that localization btw :)